# Starting GridGain in debug mode

Tags: java, gridgain

Need to figure out why my code is not working, need more information.
Debug messages would probably help.

How to start GridGain nodes in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start GridGain in debug mode, add additional JVM option

```
-DGRIDGAIN_DEBUG_ENABLED=true
```

in GridGain launch script and uncomment the following section in GRIDGAIN_HOME/config/default-log4j.xml file:

```
<category name="org.gridgain">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```